# Order the columns returned by a query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT RE1.NAME AS NAME1,RE2.NAME AS NAME2 
FROM RATING R1,RATING R2,REVIEWER RE1,REVIEWER RE2
WHERE R1.RID > R2.RID 
  AND R1.MID  = R2.MID 
  AND RE1.RID = R1.RID 
  AND RE2.RID = R2.RID;
```

The output is

```
NAME1     NAME2

CHRIS     BRITTANY
ASHLEY    CHRIS
JAMES     ELIZABETH
```

I want to return the table in such a way that the rows are in alphabetical order, i.e. the output should be:

```
NAME1     NAME2

BRITTANY   CHRIS
ASHLEY     CHRIS
ELIZABETH  JAMES
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle _or_ MySQL?

Comment: Whoever's voting to close this is perfectly clear and already has a good answer...

Comment: output is not in name order so I don't get it

Comment: It's about ordering the data in multiple columns within a row @Michael. i.e. if you have `chris|brittany` it should become `brittany|chris` because brittany is "lower" than chris.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `least()` and `greatest()` functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT least(RE1.NAME, re2.name) AS NAME1, greatest(re1.name, RE2.NAME) AS NAME2 
FROM RATING R1,RATING R2,REVIEWER RE1,REVIEWER RE2
WHERE R1.RID > R2.RID 
  AND R1.MID  = R2.MID 
  AND RE1.RID = R1.RID 
  AND RE2.RID = R2.RID;
```

You should also learn proper `join` syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT least(RE1.NAME, re2.name) AS NAME1, greatest(re1.name, RE2.NAME) AS NAME2 
from rating r1 join
     rating r2
     on R1.RID > R2.RID AND R1.MID  = R2.MID and
     reviewer re1
     on RE1.RID = R1.RID join
     reviewer re2
     on RE2.RID = R2.RID  ;
```

EDIT:

If your database doesn't support these two functions, you can easily do the same things with a `case` statement:

```
select distinct (case when RE1.NAME < re2.name then re1.name else re2.name end) AS NAME1,
       (case when RE1.NAME < re2.name then re2.name else re1.name end) as NAME2
. . .
```

As for the issue with `NULL`s.  The original data has the names populated and the joins are all inner joins, so `NULL` did not seem to be an issue.

Comment: `least()` and `greatest()`, in Oracle at least, will return a NULL if possible... which may cause some problems.

Comment: thx a lot..that works..but is there any way i can do it using "order by"??

Comment: @user2553189 . . . No.  `order by` orders rows, not columns.

Comment: FWIW, the question is tagged with `mysql` and `oracle`, and both of these implementations support the functions `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()`.  So it's all good in this case.  But those functions are not in the SQL specification, so other RDBMS brands might not support them.